# How to integrate custom bootstrap theme in activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, activeadmin

How can I integrate a custom theme like https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/inspinia-responsive-admin-theme-WB0R5L90S into a Rails ActiveAdmin project? Is this even possible?

Comment: You can't , you can use this already build themes like this https://github.com/paladini/activeadmin-themes

Answer (score 3):

I think you can try already build themes which are only for active-admin rails by this you can achieve great UI for active-admin. These are easy to implement, just go through this link https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki/Themes

Comment: Active Bootstrap Skin continues to be one of the most popular, YMMV.